# Scheduled task not ending before new run

Tags: scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task on Windows Server 2019 that is a web service. I'm suspecting that there is some kind of resource leak as performance degrades after a couple of days and restart clears it up.

So, while I work with devs to troubleshoot, I set up a trigger to run it daily and put put the action for If the task is already running to: stop the existing instance.

However, when the rerun is triggered, I can see by the process ID that a new set of processes are run before the previous instance is killed and after a minute, only the original instance remains.

How can I make sure that the process from previous run is killed before starting a new instance?

[image: screen cap of trigger logs]

Comment: What is in the Scheduled Tasks event log?

Comment: added event logs to post

Comment: and our glass balls is known for, that we know what you running, joke aside, no information about the configuration and environment, no research can be seen, atm offtopic, please read carefully [ask] and Improve your question

Comment: I did read the how to ask, only thing that may be relevant that I omitted was the precise Windows version, which I doubt there is difference in behavior in any of the in-support Windows version that has task scheduler (I also tested Win11). I edited question to add that info. Let me know what else I may have missed. Also I did do research on google and in search and nothing matched my scenario before I asked, but not sure why it needs to be a part of the question and was not mentioned that it must be stated in the how to ask.